# I suceed to clone an issue... but the clone is the issue itself :-(

Tags: properties, permissions, clone, jira

For a few days, the cloning of issues does not work anyway. I verified my permission scheme, and concerned users, can both create/modify issues, and modify reporters... but it still does not work.

The only change I made is the use of jira.permission.edit.user permission on each JIRA status in my workflow. In my permission scheme, I allowed users to modify users in general, but in my Workflow, using jira.permission.edit.users, I restricted this right for all status since the 2nd status... is that a problem ? do I have to allow cloning issue using any properties on each status ? anything else ?

I suceed to clone an issue... but the clone of my issue is my issue itself with original summary even I specified another one... Anyone has an idea ?

Any help greatly appreciated,

Thanks a lot,

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

Those workflow properties are not particularly well documented. I'd use the permission scheme instead if you can